# rbind data frames with values with different decimal numbers

Tags: r, decimal, rbind

In this example I `rbind` two data.frames, and the result is that all values have two decimal numbers. However, I want to have no decimal numbers in row 1 and 2.

```
one <- data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,3,4), ncol=2)); one
two <- data.frame(matrix(c(1.63,8.88,9.17,2.31), ncol=2)); two
rbind(one, two)
```

Comment: You may need to store in a `list` otherwise due to type promotion there will be a single class i.e. `list(one, two)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` but this will convert your variables into characters (rather than numeric), i.e.

```
d1 <- rbind(one, two)
d1[] <- lapply(d1, function(i) sprintf('%.6g', i))
```

which gives,

> ```
>     X1   X2
> 1    1    3
> 2    2    4
> 3 1.63 9.17
> 4 8.88 2.31
> ```

However the structure is,

```
str(d1)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ X1: chr  "1" "2" "1.63" "8.88"
 $ X2: chr  "3" "4" "9.17" "2.31"
```

If you convert it to numeric, you will again get those decimals, i.e.

```
sapply(d1, as.numeric)
#       X1   X2
#[1,] 1.00 3.00
#[2,] 2.00 4.00
#[3,] 1.63 9.17
#[4,] 8.88 2.31
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
test<-formatC(as.matrix(two),digits=2,format="f")
rbind(one,test)
```